# this.$refs.selectedImages.files.map is not a function - vue electron

Tags: file, vue.js, electron

I'm trying to use `map` function in my vue component. I have a file upload input that will accept multiple files. Since I'm working with electron, I can't pass directly the files to the backend of the app so I want to use the `Array.prototype.map()` function to get files path and proces them after passing the array using the `ipcRenderer.send()` function. Anyway I get always this error `this.$refs.selectedImages.files.map is not a function` how I can fix it?

Here is the actual code I'm trying

```
    handleFiles() {
      this.files = this.$refs.selectedImages.files.map( (file) => file.path ); //this will cause the error
    }, //
    processFiles() {
      this.isLoading = true;
    
      window.ipcRenderer.send('processFiles', this.files);
      
      window.ipcRenderer.on('', (event, data) => {
        console.log(ecent, data);
        saveAs(data, 'processed.mfs')
      });
    }
```

**UPDATE**

To try solve the problem I'm looping the FilesList to extract the path of each file and then pass it using `ipcRenderer`. The problem is that I'm not able to get the message on the `background.js` and I'm not sure why.

```
this.$refs.selectedImages.files.forEach( (file) => {
 this.files.push(file.path) // this will push into the array the path of each file
})

window.ipcRenderer.send('processFiles', this.files);

//background.js

import { ipcMain } from 'electron'

ipcMain.on('processFiles', (event, data) => {
 console.log(event, data) // the message will not arrive
})
```

Comment: Move your `ipcRenderer.on` statement into `created`.  As it is above, you define a new renderer listener every time you call `processFiles`, and you send the first message before any listeners are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object is actually not an array, and has no `.map` method.  But you can access the files like this:

```js
const files = this.$refs.selectedImages.files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   console.log(files[i]);
}
```

Comment: I nedd to pass the files using `ipcRenderer` of electron so I want to avoid to pass each single file and send multiple times the same event to backend, is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't use electron but it looks like you could send the whole `this.files` object as it is now.  Try just removing the `.map`

Comment: I need to test but I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081902/unable-to-pass-objects-arrays-in-ipcrenderer-an-object-could-not-be-cloned-even) and seems that the file object can't be passed using `ipcRenderer` ? If I try I get `Error: An object could not be cloned.`

Comment: Ok I see.  It looks like that question/answers is using a `path` property that I don't see on the individual file objects, so I'm not sure.  I don't use electron, I thought your issue was only with trying to use `.map` on a `FileList` object

Comment: using map on the file object will give me the error as the title of this question. I've tried to do a `forEach` on the file list object and then push into an array the `files.path` but the it seems that the `ipcRenderer` isn't sending the data to `ipcMain`.

Comment: Right, the `.map` error is the one I explained how to fix.  Since I don't use electron, I can't help with the problem specific to electron.  As I said in my earlier comment, there is no `.path` property on these file objects.  Check the console when using my answer to see what properties are available.

Comment: not right, I have the path for each file in the list and I can log it in the console, maybe it's not available for file upload on the web, but electron works locally :)