# How to pass Model as an argument in ipcMain.handle

Tags: electron

I want to create a reusable function in Electron.js to handle Saving data irrespective of the model(e.g User, Employee, Product),so I passed Model as an argument, then call the specific Model during when the function is called.
but I get this error

**Error: Expected handler to be a function, but found type 'object'**

This is my code

```
const User = require( '../database/models/Users.js');
ipcMain.handle('user:create', saveData(User));

async function saveData(_, data,Model) {
  try {
    const user = await Model.insert(data);
    return user;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ipcMain.handle('user:create', saveData(User));` call function `saveData(User)` after app is started and it returns object. if you want to assign function to `'user:create'` then without parameters it's `ipcMain.handle('user:create', saveData);` but with parameters it's.

```
ipcMain.handle('user:create', () => saveData(User));
```

is the same as

```
ipcMain.handle('user:create', function () {
   return saveData(User)
});
```

Comment: Could you maybe expand your answer to explain why this solution will work? Thanks!

Comment: @Lukas, i when i use your method i got this error, Error: An object could not be cloned.

Comment: Because you probably just created one object and you're trying to create same without changing anything.

Comment: Now it's problem with your function `saveData`

Comment: @lukas, is there no work around it,  creating saveData for each model sucks

Comment: Check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081902/unable-to-pass-objects-arrays-in-ipcrenderer-an-object-could-not-be-cloned-even

Comment: @lukas, my problem is different, i am able to receive the user data when pass two argument to savaData(_,data) callback fucntion , but i have to create saveUser(_,data), saveProduct(_,data) ,saveEmployee(_,data) for each model. To avoid this that is while a want to add a third argument which is the model saveData(_,data,Model) then add the specific model during execution e.g ipcMain.handle('user:create',()=>saveData(specificModel)) .